# Reverse Poisson Distribution problem

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I was recently solving a quiz on Poisson distribution and I encountered this question

> A call center receives an average of • 4.5 calls every 5 minutes. Each agent can handle one of these calls over the 5 minute period. If a call is received, but no agent is available to take it, then that caller will be placed on hold. Assuming that the calls follow a Poisson distribution, what is the minimum number of agents needed on duty so that calls are placed on hold at most 10% of the time?

I figured out this was a case of finding K while we are given the expected probability in the question itself.

> what is the minimum number of agents needed on duty so that calls are
>   placed on hold at most 10% of the time?

I could not event determine the lambda and X to solve this question.
PS : The correct answer was 7 agents.A detailed explanation will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are being asked to focus on a typical 5-minute period of time.
Then the average number $X$ of incoming calls within 5 minutes has the distribution $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 4.5).$ A bar plot of this distribution is shown below:

[image]

**Poisson Model:** Computations with the Poisson PDF $P(X = i) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^i}{i!},$ where $\lambda = 4.5,$ show that $P(X \le 6) =  0.8311 < 0.9$ and
$P(X \le 7) = 0.9134.$ Thus seven agents would suffice to serve
incoming customers at least 90% of the time.

**Trial and error with Poisson CDF:** Computations using
R statistical software (where the CDF of a Poisson distribution is denoted `ppois`) are as follows:

```
ppois(6, 4.5)
## 0.8310506
ppois(7, 4.5)
## 0.9134135
```

**Using a Poisson quantile function:** If you have such software available, you can use the *inverse CDF*
or *quantile function* `qpois` to get to the answer without
exploration.

```
qpois(.9, 4.5)
## 7
```

*Note:* Without knowing the context of this problem in your course, I suppose something like this is the approach you are expected to take. However, there
are some unstated assumptions involved. A complete analysis of such
a problem would involve finding the required number of servers $k$ required in an **M/M/k queue** (at steady state) that are sufficient to keep the average number of customers in the
system below $k$ 90% of the time. This would involve knowing the
exponential arrival rate $\lambda = 4.5$ per five minutes or $0.9$ per
minute, and knowing the exponential rate (often denoted $\mu)$ at
which each server can finish serving customers.

For starters: here are a few unstated assumptions: (a) No agents are busy at the beginning of the 5-minute period. (b) Each agent handles only one call within this period. (c) We are not concerned whether
agents are still handling calls from this 5-minute period ends and the next begins.

Comment: maybe I was making too many assumptions at first and did not look it in a simplistic manner.
I did try it using a cdf with hit and trial like you mentioned, but accepting lambda to be 4.5 instead of 0.9 was not clear to me.

Considering the given assumptions, I believe you have provided the simplest solution to this.

Thanks a lot